# Using a plugin in a Gant task with Grails

Tags: grails, gant

I have a gant task I wrote using:

```
grails create-script my-script
```

And I'm using some code from a plugin I have in my build config:

```
compile ":csv:0.3.1"
```

However, it isn't on the classpath when I execute my gant script.  I have another dependency I'm using in the dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    build 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:2.0.0-m25'
    build 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:2.0.0-m25'
}
```

That are loaded on the classpath.  However, my plugin code isn't.  How can I get the plugin code to work with the gant script?

**Update:**

Here is how my script starts:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClasspath")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsCompile")

target(main: "Creates JIRA tasks for Content Developers based on given lesson file.") {
    depends(compile)
    ....
}
```

Comment: How does the script look like? Have you made sure that the plugin is accessed in the script after the `compile` target since the plugin is defined in compile scope. Some thing like `depends(compile,..)`  should be the first line in the target.

Comment: I've updated the question, but adding the depends on compile didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was to use the following:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

target(main: "Creates JIRA tasks for Content Developers based on given lesson file.") {
    depends( bootstrap )
    ...
}
```

However, I had a transitive dependency pulling in spring framework version 2.5.6 which was a mess.  And I was getting the following:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;
```

The fix for that was the following:

```
dependencies {
    build( 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:2.0.0-m25' ) {
        excludes([group: "org.springframework", name:"spring-context", version:"2.5.6"],
                 [group:"org.springframework", name:"spring-beans", version:"2.5.6"],
                 [group:"org.springframework", name:"spring-core", version:"2.5.6"])
    }
    build('com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:2.0.0-m25') {
        excludes([group: "org.springframework", name:"spring-context", version:"2.5.6"],
                 [group:"org.springframework", name:"spring-beans", version:"2.5.6"],
                 [group:"org.springframework", name:"spring-core", version:"2.5.6"])
    }
}
```